# Python: Receiving dictionary or list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

From an API I received JSON data which contains several dictionaries in a list.

```
result = [{u'username': u'someuser', 
           u'archived': False,
           u'locked': False}, 
          {u'username': u'someotheruser', 
           u'archived': False,
           u'locked': False}]
```

As I get several of these, I add them to a list

```
data = []
data.extend(result)
```

But if I query this API for a single entry, I just get a single dictionary and .extend does not work anymore.

```
result = {u'username': u'someuser', 
          u'archived': False,
          u'locked': False}
```

But I really would like to use the same function for this as the only thing that changes is the URL to query from. Any idea how to do this or should I made a own function just for single queries?

Comment: check the type and use `append` if it's a dictionary?

Comment: Surely you can test if you are making a query for a single entry or a series, then switch to using `list.append()` as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function to use `append` if the `result` is a dictionary, and `extend` if is a list:

```
def myextend(data, result):
    if isinstance(result, dict):
        data.append(result)
    elif isinstance(result, list):
        data.extend(result)
```